# Symfony 4 redirect 404 error to my controller

Tags: symfony4

I'm trying to catch the 404 error and redirect it to custom controller, so I could get some data from database. I find this article https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/controller/error_pages.html

and overide custom 404 page by creating structure **templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/error404.html.twig**

but in that case it is imposible to load data from database to 404 page. Is it possible to do what I'm asking - just catch 404 error and process it in my own controller, other errors I want to be processed by default ErrorController?

Comment: You can use your own error controller, see here: [https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-errorcontroller](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-errorcontroller)

Comment: I know, but in that case I will haw to manage all other errors. And I want just to catch 404 and the rest of the errors were handled through a standard controller.

Comment: Ok, how about injecting a service into twig template [https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html#referencing-services] and all the loading can be done in service. I don't really know if it will work in the error template though.

Comment: And I find out that if you overriding the default error templates it's imposible to use Twig Reference from Symfony ( I tried **path()**, **url()** and tag **trans**). If I use them they call 500 error.